# How to exit from Nested Graph Navigation Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have just one Home Fragment and one Nested Graph form Registration with 3 Fragments inside.

When you get the end of registration and press "End" button, the navigation return to Home. But when I press back button from Home, the navigation return to last step to registration. As if all the previous fragments were left on the stack (Also LeakCanary throws memory leak warnings at that moment).

[image]

I need to close that circuit once the user exits the nested graph. This is possible? What is the best way to do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: you can use `app:popUpTo="@id/yourNestedGraphRootId"` and 
        `app:popUpToInclusive="true"`  check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61031383/android-navigation-component-change-root-fragment/61031774#61031774

Comment: It works! I read about "popUpTo example: circular logic" in official documentation and that's the solution: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#pop Thanks!